# How much HP do the healing potions restore?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm still fairly low-level, and a minor healing potion still gets me to full HP, even if I'm almost dying. How many HPs do the different kind of Healing potions restore?

Comment: They restore a percentage according to [the](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_Potions#In_Diablo_III) wikis](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Potions#Diablo_III). Because of this, fixed HP numbers will be relative to your health.

Comment: That's not what I've experienced, as I said a minor healing potion gets me to full health at the moment. If it was percentage based I should have seen a much lesser HP gain

Comment: @skovacs1 I think you're confusing health potions with health globes, which *do* return a percentage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/potion/:

- [Minor Health Potion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/minor-health-potion): 250 life, req. level 1
- [Lesser Health Potion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/lesser-health-potion): 400 life, req. level 6
- [Health Potion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/health-potion): 550 life, req. level 11
- [Greater Health Potion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/greater-health-potion): 1000 life, req. level 16
- [Major Health Potion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/major-health-potion): 1600 life, req. level 21
- [Super Health Potion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/super-health-potion): 2500 life, req. level 26
- [Heroic Health Potion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/heroic-health-potion): 4500 life, req. level 37
- [Resplendent Health Potion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/resplendent-health-potion): 6500 life, req. level 47
- [Runic Health Potion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/runic-health-potion): 9000 life, req. level 53
- [Mythic Health Potion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/mythic-health-potion): 12500 life, req. level 58